# Using an AngularJS service to construct html partials

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, partial, angularjs-service

I'm trying to populate an html list using AngularJs in the following way. I want to create a service that takes an html partial, populates it's attributes in the constructor and returns it. Below is my example for this.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cfwvIcSJlYdxKoSFZ3qt?p=preview)

js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','listElemService', function($scope,listElemService) {

$scope.listElemArray = [];  

var testParam1 = {};
var tester = listElemService(testParam1); 
$scope.listElemArray.push(new listElemService(testParam1));

var testParam2 = {};
testParam2.url = "http://www.yahoo.com";
testParam2.imgSrc = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000416430559/3fab1a175e2a87010f23435e0aea0f61_400x400.jpeg";

$scope.listElemArray.push(new listElemService(testParam2));

}]).factory('listElemService',function(){

    var ListElemConstructor = function(params) {
      this.initialize = function() {
      this.url = params.url;
      this.imgSrc = params.imgSrc;

      /*
      want to be able to construct list element below
      from listElemView.html based on params.url and params.imgSrc
      */
      this.html =  "Html Placeholder";
    };

    this.initialize();
};

return ListElemConstructor;

});
```

main html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.1/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.1"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>

      <li ng-repeat="x in listElemArray">
        {{x.html}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Html Partial that I'd like to 'bring in' to my service and populate:

```
<li>
  <img src=""/>
  <a href=""></a>
</li>
```

Comment: you use factory wrong, in your code - you return constructor function, and use it like simple function, but constructor return nothing

Comment: Okay thanks, I go the Plunker working now, by using the 'new' keyword. Does this fix what you're pointing out?

Comment: also why you need `{{x.html}}` if you can simply `<img src="{{x.imgSrc}}"/>
  <a href="x.url"></a>`?

Comment: I want to construct that in the service based on the html partial to have more modular html.

Comment: so you can use _ngInclude_, you have many different partials? or simply one???

Comment: I don't have very many partials but doesn't it make design sense to create everything related to this list element in one place?

Answer (score 1):

I not sure that you need *x.html*, seems like you need or inline template like

```
<li ng-repeat="x in listElemArray">
    <img src="{{x.imgSrc}}"/>
    <a href="{{x.url}}"></a>
</li>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'listElemService',
  function($scope, listElemService) {

    $scope.name = 'World';

    $scope.listElemArray = [];

    var testParam2 = {};
    testParam2.url = "http://www.yahoo.com";
    testParam2.imgSrc = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000416430559/3fab1a175e2a87010f23435e0aea0f61_400x400.jpeg";

    $scope.listElemArray.push(new listElemService(testParam2));

    console.log("$scope.listElem: ", $scope.listElemArray);

  }
]).factory('listElemService', function() {

  var ListElemConstructor = function(params) {
    console.log("list elem const url: " + params.url);
    this.initialize = function() {
      this.url = params.url;
      this.imgSrc = params.imgSrc;

      var self = this;
    };

    this.initialize();

  };

  return ListElemConstructor;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>

    <li ng-repeat="x in listElemArray">
      <img ng-src="{{x.imgSrc}}" />
      <a ng-href="{{x.url}}">{{x.url}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

or use [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

```
<li ng-repeat="x in listElemArray" ng-include="'listElemView.html'">
```

Sample on plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5W4L1NoyiaLs7M3lCLZm?p=preview

Comment: It is better to use `ngSrc`, instead of `src` attribute of image.

Comment: @CuriousMind yep, in snippet use _ng-src_ and _ng-href_

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `ngBindHtml` to insert HTML text in the list items. Hence your code may look like this

```
<li ng-repeat="x in listElemArray" ngBindHtml="x.html">
</li>
```

Check the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml). Also check the section which says that you should use `angular-sanitize.js`, to ensure security.